# Counting number of network connections in linux

Tags: networking

I see these two commands that counts the number of connections to the server. However, there is large difference in the output of these two.

**To calculate and count, number of connection currently established from each IP address with server.**

```
$ netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | wc -l
154
```

**To Print ESTABLISHED connections instead of all connections, and displays the connections count for each IP**

```
$ netstat -ntu | grep ESTAB | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | wc -l
62
```

I would like to know what is **un**established connections then (154-62)?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/173535/what-are-close-wait-and-time-wait-states

Comment: Are all states considered as active? I mean when I set ServerLimit to 500 in Apache, does that include all connection states or only ESTABLISHED?

Comment: Most likely only ESTABLISHED

Answer (score 0):

TCP connections have many states, for example: *ESTABLISHED*, *SYN_SENT*, *SYN_RECV*, *FIN_WAIT1*, *CLOSE_WAIT*,... All of them, except *ESTABLISHED* belong to your *unestablished* category.

Note that from a resource point of view they all take up a socket until they actually end. The list of states and their meaning is in the [manpage for `netstat`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat)